# Inserting a subquery with concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

Table1

| ID | Subtotal | Tax |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.7 |
| 4 | 1.25 | 0.5 |

Table2

| ID | GrandTotal |
| --- | --- |

Table3

| ID | Item | Available |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Book | Y |
| 2 | Apple | N |
| 3 | Coffee | Y |
| 4 | Pencil | Y |

I want to insert values into Table2, where GrandTotal = the sum of Subtotal and Tax for each row in Table1. I only want to do inserts for when the IDs in Table1 don't exist in Table2. I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
(ID, GrandTotal)
VALUES
(
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            SubTotal + Tax AS GrandTotal
        FROM Table1
        WHERE ID IN (
            SELECT ID
            FROM Table3
            WHERE Available = 'Y'
        )
        AND ID NOT IN (
            SELECT ID FROM Table2
        )
    )
)
```

However, it's throwing the following errors:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

> There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

I'm thinking part of this error is because it's not liking how I'm trying to add the Subtotal and Tax columns together, or concatenating them. How can I fix my query to get around these errors?

Comment: Probably start by removing the `values()` wrapper, so your query becomes valid `insert … select` statement.

Comment: The above changes should fix your error.  For performance you can change the IN and NOT in to either joins or EXISTS NOT EXIST clauses.

Comment: @GMB So just `INSERT INTO Table2 (ID, GrandTotal) (SELECT ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the query:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
(ID, GrandTotal)
SELECT
    ID,
    SubTotal + Tax AS GrandTotal
FROM Table1
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM Table3
    WHERE Available = 'Y'
)
AND ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID FROM Table2
)
```

SQL Server uses INSERT INTO SELECT, not INSERT INTO VALUES SELECT. Could've also replaced the IN/NOT IN clauses with EXISTS/NOT EXISTS, but there were only about 100 rows that had to be inserted, so it wasn't terrible (for now).

Comment: You can (should) also remove the parentheses around the `SELECT`; they are not necessary.